# Adding attribute to Model in Spring, but it needs to call different objects, depending on previous input

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am creating a Spring, Thymeleaf application and I stumbled upon something, which I cannot find an answer to, while searching, nor can i come up with something.

So I am making a page in which a user must input some values in a couple of fields and then add offer to the database. Two of the fields in the html template will be  dropdowns. In the first dropdown the respondent will see countries, which exist in the database. I add them to the model -

```
model.addAttribute("countries", countryService.getAllCountries())
```

after that I present them in the html with thymeleaf expressions.

Afterwards, in the second dropdown, I want to show the towns for the respective country, however I cannot do the same for them, since I do not know, which country will be selected, or can i?

Is there a way to do that without JS or it is the only way. And if JS is mandatory, could you give me some directions on where to look for information on how to do that, please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In other words, you need a way to filter the second dropdown depending on the content of the first dropdown? If that's the case, why don't you tell/notify the server whenever something is selected in the countries dropdown? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Jetto, 

Yes indeed that's what i want.

However since I have almost to zero experience in JS I was able to compromise and add both objects in one dropdown and show each city and under the city - the respective towns. 
I will now start searching on how this is doable with JS.

Comment: I THINK your approach is not correct. I capitalize that because I have no experience with Thymeleaf in particular, but most (if not all) client-side libraries/frameworks have a way to communicate changes to the server-side. Nowadays we use `events` for that. I'd look first how Thymeleaf implements events, before jumping right into JS. That being said, going with JS could be the right way after all.